# Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to export some data from sharepoint list to csv and I got this error:

$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "D:\LX.csv" -NoTypeInformation

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:20 char:2
+     $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

the code is really easy

```
$URL = "https://mysite"
$List = "Page Contents"

$Web = Get-SPWeb $URL

$web
$spList = $Web.Lists[$List]
$Items = $spList.GetItems()


$listItems = $spList.Items

foreach($item in $listItems) {

    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "PageID" -value $item["PageID"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Html Component" -value $item["Html Component"]

    #Add the object with property to an Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}
```

Comment: Why `foreach` and append items? Why not just `$splist.Items | Select-Object PageID,"Html Component"`?

Comment: Also, where do you instantiate `$ListItemCollection`? What sort of object is it?

Comment: just copied the sample code from another blog

Comment: It's good practice to reference where the code came from when you copy it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

- `$ListItemCollection` is of type `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`, not an array.
- Make sure that it is an *array*  (e.g., `$ListItemCollection = @()`) for `+=` to work as intended, i.e., for `+=` to append an element<sup>[1]</sup>.
- Note that commands that *typically* output *multiple* items - which are then collected in a regular `[object[]]` array, if assigned to a variable - output only a *scalar* if the command situationally happens to return only *one* item; in other words: a single-item output array is automatically *unwrapped*.
- Therefore, if there's a chance that a command situationally returns only a *single* object, yet **you need the result to *always* be an *array*, use `@(...)`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators); e.g.:

  ```
       # @(...) ensures that $file is an array, even if just 1 file matches
       $files = @(Get-ChildItem *.txt)
  ```

---

The error message implies that `$ListItemCollection` is of type `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]` and *not* an array.

Since type `[pscustomobject]` (`[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`) does not have a static `op_Addition` method, you cannot use the `+` operator with an instance of it as the LHS.
(Type-specific operators are implemented as static `op_*` methods).

You can verify this as follows:

```
PS> (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSObject) + 1 # !! Breaks
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'
```

If you want to inspect a given type for operator support, use a command such as the following, using the `[datetime]` type as an example:

```
PS> [datetime] | Get-Member -Force -Static -Type Method op_*

   TypeName: System.DateTime

Name                  MemberType Definition
----                  ---------- ----------
op_Addition           Method     static datetime op_Addition(datetime d, timespan t)
op_Equality           Method     static bool op_Equality(datetime d1, datetime d2)
op_GreaterThan        Method     static bool op_GreaterThan(datetime t1, datetime t2)
op_GreaterThanOrEqual Method     static bool op_GreaterThanOrEqual(datetime t1, datetime t2)
op_Inequality         Method     static bool op_Inequality(datetime d1, datetime d2)
op_LessThan           Method     static bool op_LessThan(datetime t1, datetime t2)
op_LessThanOrEqual    Method     static bool op_LessThanOrEqual(datetime t1, datetime t2)
op_Subtraction        Method     static datetime op_Subtraction(datetime d, timespan t), static timespan op_Subtraction(datetime d1, datetime d2)
```

Note:

- The "primitive" .NET data types do *not* have such methods, because operator support for them is built in.
- Similarly, it is PowerShell itself that implements `+` for arrays and collections (`[object[]]`, `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`, ...), though note that:

  1. a new instance is invariably constructed, and
  2. the result is *always* of type `[object[]]` (unless you use a type-constrained variable that converts the array back to a different collection type).
- `-Force` is needed, because `Get-Member` hides the `op_*` methods by default.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, a *new* array is created behind the scenes, because arrays are *immutable*. In loops this can be a performance concern; if so, use a *mutable* collection type such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` and append to it with its `.Add()` method.</sup>