# Upload file to SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I would like to create a program in PowerShell to upload files to Sharepoint on schedule (using Task Scheduler)

I was looking for solution and I found [this interesting article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40048.sharepoint-20162013online-how-to-upload-files-to-sharepoint-document-libraries-by-powershell-automation.aspx).

Based on this I wrote this script below:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking;
(System.Reflection.Assembly)::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.MemoryStream")
Clear-Host
$cred = Get-Credential "emailaddress@domain.com"
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($cred.Username, $cred.Password)
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://")
$clientCOntext.Credentials = $credentials
if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) {Write-host "Connected to site" -ForegroundColor Green}

Function UploadFileToLibrary(){
$docLib - $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("IT Documents");
$clientContext.Load($docLib);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
$rootFolder = $docLib.RootFolder
$Folder = "\\10.x.x.x\xpbuild$\IT\Level0\scresult\Upload";
$FilesInRoot = Get-ChildItem - Path $Folder | ? {$_.psIsContainer -eq $False}
Foreach ($File in ($FilesInRoot))
{
$startDTM = (Get-Date)
}Write-Host "Uploading File" $File.Name "to" $docLib.Title -ForegroundColor Blue
UploadFile $rootFolder $File $false
$endDTM = (Get-Date)
Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time : $(($endDTM-$startDTM).totalseconds) seconds"
}

Function UploadFile ($SPListFolder, $File, $CheckInRequired){
$FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($File.FullName,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $True
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.Url = $File
$UploadedFile = $SPListFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)

If($CheckInRequired){
$clientContext.Load($UploadedFile)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
If($uploadedFile.CheckOutType -ne "none"){
    $UploadedFile.CheckIn("Checked in by Administrator", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
    }
}
$clientContext.Load($UploadedFile)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
}
UploadFileToLibrary
```

When I tried to execute this I see that connection is active but I got an error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
At C:\PowerShell\UploadSharepoint.ps1:11 char:1
+ $docLib - $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("IT Documents");
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Subtraction:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\PowerShell\UploadSharepoint.ps1:12 char:1
+ $clientContext.Load($docLib);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "List 'IT Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://'."
At C:\PowerShell\UploadSharepoint.ps1:13 char:1
+ $clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

Comment: I think this could help with your first issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911366/method-invocation-failed-because-system-management-automation-psobject-doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell if any new problem occur once you fix that one, but given that the 2nd and 3rd error is caused by incorrect assignment of `$docLib` variable, changing `-` to `=`should resolve these three:

```
   HERE |
$docLib = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("IT Documents");

# Below uses $docLib so it cannot be executed properly unless $docLib is assigned correct value
$clientContext.Load($docLib);

# And below fails as the above is not executed successfully
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider accepting the answer then if it helped, so that others can find it and use easily.